# React date format - RangeError: Invalid time value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a date in react app like

```
const messageDate = new Date(Date.parse(createdDate))
const options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' } as const
const displayDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options).format(messageDate)
```

createdDate is from a GQL call

This seems to work and I have a formatted date.

I'm writing jest test with react-testing library

I'm not writing any test to test this function but the component it sits in, when I run the tests I can an error on `format(messageDate)`

```
RangeError: Invalid time value
```

Does the date function look ok, what could be causing this

Comment: please show some example value of `createdDate` and `messageDate`. The exception you are getting simply states that `messageDate` is an invalid date.

Comment: Can you `console.log` `messageDate`?

Comment: ---createdDate--- 2023-01-10T14:22:53.826Z

Comment: ---messageDate--- Tue Jan 10 2023 14:22:53 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)

Comment: ---displayDate--- 10 January at 14:22

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with

```
const messageDate = new Date(createdDate)
const options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' } as const
const displayDate = messageDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options)
```